# Replacing Close Icon with a Button in Modal Window

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using JQuery UI to open a Modal Windows. Right now the Modal Windows has and X Icon on the right side of the header titlebar to close the Modal Window. If possible, I would like to replace the X icon with a Button with label Close. I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve] so we do not have to do it. Then inspec the clos, grab the class and style it yourself

Comment: Show us what your modal code looks like and what (if anything) you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Want to expand upon the code presented by @freginold, which is a very valid solution.

```js
$(function() {
  var $dlg = $("#dialog").dialog({
    classes: {
      "ui-dialog": "close-label"
    }
  });

  $(".close-label .ui-dialog-titlebar-close")
    .removeClass("ui-button-icon-only")
    .css({
      height: "auto",
      width: "auto",
      "text-indent": 0,
      padding: "0 .2em"
    })
    .html("Close");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/start/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic Dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @CarlosSosa glad to hear that. I hope that you will mark one as the answer that you used.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way jQuery UI sets up the close button, any text you might set using the `closeText` property is not visible by default. (See the [jQuery UI dialog widget page](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-close) for more info.)

However, you can override the jQuery UI CSS rules to show text in the close button. Here's an example of what that would look like:

```js
$(function() {

  $("#dialog").dialog(); // create dialog modal

  var xBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("ui-icon-closethick")[0].parentNode;
  xBtn.style.height = "auto";
  xBtn.style.width = "auto";
  xBtn.style.textIndent = 0;
  xBtn.innerHTML = "Close"; // set close button text

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/start/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

You can apply other styles to the close button to make it appear how you want it to -- padding, margin, font, etc. This is just a basic example.

If you want to customize this example, assign the text for your close button to `xBtn.innerHTML`.

Comment: Thanks so much @freginold. This really helped.